# RAD package: arguments imply differing number of rows: 126, 120

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to use the R package RAD to detect anomalies in a time series. But when I do `AnomalyDetection.rpca(1:150)`, I get:

```
Error in data.frame(X.transform = X.transform, L.transform = L.transform,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 154, 150
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix((j - j.global.mean)/j.global.sd, nrow = frequency) :
  data length [150] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [7]
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/Netflix/Surus/issues/7

Comment: @J_F That helps, thanks